# Urllib2 Seems to Ignore Proxy Settings

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2

I'm behind a proxy and would like to use urllib2 to access external sites. If I set up the proxy in my environment, I can access external sites. When I set a proxy in urllib2, it seems to be ignored and the access fails.

The code I'm using is:

```
import urllib2
import os
import sys

uri = "https://www.python.org"

http_proxy_server = "192.168.12.20"
http_proxy_port = "8082"
http_proxy = "http://%s:%s" % (http_proxy_server, http_proxy_port)

def open_url_no_proxy():
    sys.stdout.write('Proxy (none): ')
    proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
    try:
        opener.open(uri)
        sys.stdout.write('PASS\n')
    except urllib2.URLError:
        sys.stdout.write('FAIL\n')

def open_url_system_proxy():
    sys.stdout.write('Proxy (system): ')
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    try:
        opener.open(uri)
        sys.stdout.write('PASS\n')
    except urllib2.URLError:
        sys.stdout.write('FAIL\n')

def open_url_installed_opener():
    sys.stdout.write('Proxy (installed): ')
    proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": http_proxy})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
    try:
        opener.open(uri)
        sys.stdout.write('PASS\n')
    except urllib2.URLError:
        sys.stdout.write('FAIL\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['no_proxy'] = 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    os.environ['NO_PROXY'] = 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    os.environ['http_proxy'] = http_proxy
    os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = http_proxy
    open_url_system_proxy()
    open_url_no_proxy()
    open_url_system_proxy()
    open_url_installed_opener()
    open_url_system_proxy()
```

The response I get on my system is:

```
$ python proxytest2.py 
Proxy (system): PASS
Proxy (none): FAIL
Proxy (system): PASS
Proxy (installed): FAIL
Proxy (system): PASS
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set up only a proxy for HTTP in the line below, but you're accessing an HTTPS site:

```
 proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": http_proxy})
```

You need to modify this to

```
 proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": http_proxy, "https": http_proxy})
```